# Unable to compile jetpack compose in multi module app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to setup jetpack compose in my multi module application.But i am facing so many issues. Below is one of them.

> Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
> Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
> exception: java.io.EOFException

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

 ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
        compose_ui_version = '1.2.0'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your versions are all pretty much out of date. Please have a look at how to set up Compose in the [Quick Start](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#setup-compose) page. Using composeBom (2023.01.00) will help you in making sure your versions are correct. There is also the Compose to Kotlin [Compatibility Map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#declaring_dependencies).

In short:

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.0"
    }

 ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
        compose_compiler_version = '1.4.0'
    }
```

Comment: After updating the correct versions and removing plugin id 'kotlin-android-extensions', it's throwing UTFDataFormatException.And preview of compose is also not showing.

Comment: Well, these errors do not come from using correct versions of your dependencies. You must have other problems, but you would need to provide some code so we can help. Consider starting another question as this is presumably a different issue.